# ¿Qué característica(s) de HTML5 y HTML 5.1 determina la confianza para trabajar con el navegador que lo soporte?

Tags: javascript, html5

Es bien sabido que **HTML5** nace con la posibilidad de crear `Canvas` y `Microdata`, por eso; asumo que conocer soporte para HTML5 es:

```
var HTML5Supported = !!(window.HTMLCanvasElement && window.CanvasRenderingContext2D && document.getItems);
```

Mientras que en **HTML5.1**, buscando en la Web; podríamos detectar `Canvas 3D`:

```
var HTML51Supported = !!window.WebGLRenderingContext && WebGLRenderingContext.hasOwnProperty('prototype');
```

Éste último no estoy seguro de que sea así, ya que en [Diferencias entre HTML 5.1 y HTML5.0 según la W3C](https://www.w3.org/html/landscape/#differences-between-w3c-html-5.1-and-w3c-html-5.0), no lo encuentro que sea así.

¿Cómo creen que se pueda detectar eficazmente la *version 5.1* del *doctype HTML*?

Answer (score 12):

**No es una buena idea**, ningún browser actualmente soporta todo el standard HTML 5, mucho menos el 5.1.

Detectar la versión de HTML soportada es tan mala practica como detectar el browser o la versión del mismo.

Mejor decide buscar por las características que deseas usar independientemente de la versión de HTML/5/5.1, apoyate en librerias como [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/).

Que es [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/docs/#what-is-feature-detection)?

Ejemplo

```
  if (Modernizr.canvas) {
    alert("Este browser soporta canvas!");
  }

  if (Modernizr.webgl) {
    alert("Este browser soporta webgl!");
  }
```

Comment: Este proceso, por cierto, se conoce como *feature detection* y es el camino a seguir. Todo el ecosistema web está evolucionando hacia una dirección donde esta práctica viene integrada en los propios lenguajes con cosas como `@supports` o `CSS.supports()`.

Comment: Buena idea o NO, es la forma de el cómo lo usemos o para qué. Detectar la versión de HTML5 es detectar todas las características. El detalle es que los navegadores demoran en implementarlas. HTML5.1 está a la vuelta de la esquina, este año lo aprueban. Y Como dice @Darkhogg, el comité TC39 y la W3C crearon **@supports y CSS.supports()** respectivamente, para el apoyo a los desarrolladores. Quiere decir que nosotros podemos apoyarnos creando nuestras propias herramientas. Que por cierto, si a alguno los interesa: `var supportsCSS = !!((window.CSS && window.CSS.supports) || window.supportsCSS);`

Comment: Html 5 estaba también a la vuelta de la esquina y es la hora que ninguno de los browser lo soporta por completo, puedes hacer cosas para detectar si el browser soporta html5 y con eso jamás tendrás certeza de que features si están soportados realmente o no. Y bueno tienes razón las buenas prácticas y las recomendaciones por experiencia existen pero cada cual es libre de seguirlas o ignorarlas.

Comment: Lástima pero es cierto. Por eso, edito y mejoro la pregunta con la finalidad obtener una respuesta según mi conjetura.